# How do astronauts eat in space?

Tags: human-biology, food

If there is no gravity in space how does the food enter the stomach?
My guess is that it is due to the movement of the esophagus.Am I correct?

Comment: swallowing does not require gravity. you can test it by yourself if you stand on your head and eat something

Comment: Have you ever eaten lying down? What did you notice (or not notice?) This is very easily answered with a simple google search. They even have videos of astronauts eating in space.

Answer (score 1):

swallowing of food or water from mouth to stomach is done with the help of peristalsis action of esophagus

Then rhythmic, unidirectional waves of contractions will work to rapidly force the food into the stomach. This process works in one direction only and its sole purpose is to move food from the mouth into the stomach.

In earth it also happens but it is assisted with gravity but in space Peristalsis action is the only process by which food or water is taken to stomach .

Comment: Welcome. In this community we require answers to be accompanied by suitable sources, preferably journal papers.